# PHP htmlentities and saving the data in xml format

Tags: php, xml, save, html-entities, html-encode

Im trying to save some data into a xml file using the following PHP script:

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="google.com/maps">Go to google maps</a> and some special characters ë è & ä etc.';

$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('top');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);

$id = $doc->createAttribute('id');
$id->value = '1';
$text = $title->appendChild($id);

$text = $doc->createTextNode($string);
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

$doc->save('data.xml');

echo 'data saved!';

?>
```

I'm using htmlentities to translate all of the string into an html format, if I leave this out the special characters won't be translated to html format. this is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
  <title id="1">&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;google.com/maps&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Go to google maps&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt; and some special characters &amp;euml; &amp;egrave; &amp;amp; &amp;auml; etc.</title>
</top>
```

The ampersand of the html tags get a double html code: `&amp;lt;` and an ampersand becomes: `&amp;amp;`

Is this normal behavior? Or how can I prevent this from happening? Looks like a double encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the line:

```
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Because the text passed to createTextNode() is escaped anyway.

Update:
If you want the utf-8 characters to be escaped. You could leave that line and try to add the $string directly in createElement().

For example:

```
$title = $doc->createElement('title', $string);
$title = $root->appendChild($title);
```

In PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) it says that $string will not be escaped. I haven't tried it, but it should work.

Comment: When I remove that line the special characters won't translate to HTML code. Like ë has to become &euml; Do you know how to do this if I leave that line out?

Comment: Thx for your reply! Your right it will not escape the string if I add it directly. But now I have a XML Parsing Error: undefined entity because it can't save the &euml; in the string.

Comment: I've just tested this on my server using this [code](http://pastebin.com/Quwxmz0N) and it gave me this [result](http://pastebin.com/aEM1WbMF). Apparently it works, only quotes aren't escaped.

Comment: It works when I download the file from the server and open it but when I load it in google chrome I get an error: error on line 3 at column 107: Entity 'euml' not defined.

Comment: Thx for all your help Bojan! Except for google chrome (and maybe other browsers) it works now. This is good enough for my project.

Answer (score 2):

It is the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) that turns a `&` into `&amp;` 
When working with xml data you should not use htmlentities, as the DOMDocument will handle a `&` and not `&amp;`.

As of php 5.3 the default encoding is UTF-8, so there is no need to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: Thx for the explanation of a DOMDocument!

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

… encodes a string as HTML.

This line:

```
$text = $doc->createTextNode($string);
```

… encodes your string of HTML as XML.

This gives you an XML representation of an HTML string. When the XML is parsed you get the HTML back.

> how can I prevent this from happening?

If your goal is to store some text in an XML document. Remove the line that encodes it as HTML.

> Looks like a double encoding.

Pretty much. It is encoded twice, it just uses different (albeit very similar) encoding methods for each of the two passes.