# How to decode HTML entities when saving an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, html-entities

I have the following code in my PHP script:

```
$str = '<item></item>';
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->load('file.xml');
$items = $addon->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0);
$items->nodeValue = $str;
$xml->save('file.xml');
```

In the saved file.xml I see the following:

```
&lt;item&gt;&lt;\item&gt;
```

How can I save it in the XML file without encoding HTML entities?

Comment: If the `$str` is supposed to be a text value, that's perfectly correct, it *needs* to be escaped. Are you actually trying to *add a new `<item>` element* to the XML file?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330571/php-htmlentities-and-saving-the-data-in-xml-format and http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#106535

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually it does not help me, what I have in my XML is: <variants></variants> and I want to change it like that: <variants><item id=1>item</item></variants>, in $str I have <item id=1>item</item> and I want to insert it between <variants></variants>, that is why I use nodeValue

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOMDocumentFragment:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('file.xml'); // '<doc><items/></doc>'

$item = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$item->appendXML('<item id="1">item</item>');

$doc->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0)->appendChild($item);
$doc->save('file.xml');
```

If you're appending to the root element, use `$doc->documentElement->appendChild($item);` instead of `getElementsByTagName`.